# Magento Checkout - edit Review template

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to edit the Checkout Review template in a custom theme but I am experiencing issues when trying to re-order the table columns.

I have done the following

- edited the custom theme - app/design/frontend//default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml
- edited the base theme (as a test) - app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml
- disabled all of the Cache Management
- enabled template hints but the page doesn't render

I have altered the table class in the custom theme as follows which does show

```
<table class="data-table test" id="checkout-review-table">
```

I have re-ordered the columns in the custom theme as follows but the changes don't show

```
<th rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
<th rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty')?></th>
<th colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Price')?></th>
<th colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: tim - this is my first Magento site - where can I find the error log?

Comment: i ment not magento error log but an error log of your web-server. if page is not rendered it means (most likely) there is PHP error. its description is logged under error log of your web-server.

Comment: unfortunately unable to find any errors logged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely editing the right template, so to prevent confusion could you revert all changes to base template and work from a fresh copy of info.phtml in your custom template.

Update

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
        <th colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
        <th rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
        <th colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
            <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
</thead>
```

[image]

Comment: I "edited the base theme (as a test)" to see if somehow the base template was being displayed instead of my theme. Please refer to the original question of why the amends to info.phtml table are not showing.

Comment: reverted to base/default theme - still no luck

Comment: do you know where accordion.js gets the content to display from?

Comment: No sure if I understand you question but take a look @ /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before and If you are using SagePay or any other payment method, check the extension folder, that should have another review/info.phtml file. This is the one you're looking for.

Hope this helps,
Alex